# F# identity framework

Tags: f#, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity, entity-framework-core

I'm creating new project (just to learn). It will be written in ASP.Net 5 MVC 6 and EF 7 code first approach. Also I want to make service layer i.e. all business logic written in F# 4.0 (never wrote a line in that language except for some tutorials). This means I'm creating this project in everything new or use tools that I not used before.

Currently I have empty solution. So first task I've set before me is to create authentication logic. All tutorials show how simple it is however: I do not want to have any logic (other than view manipulation) in controllers. So I need to create a service that will be called and login/register user.

The problem is that all business logic will be written in F#. I wasn't able to find any materials on how to achieve such task. Can you guys guide me how to use Microsoft identity with code first approach in F#.

Any guide lines, tutorials (yes I've looked through uncle google) would be appreciated.

Comment: have you found a good tutorial (for you) using C#? I have no clue about the newer Identity stuff from Microsoft, but most C# code can be easily translated into F#

Comment: All tutorials that I've found are setup that all logic is in main project in controllers. And that doesn't help me much as they lack the setup I need for placing logic in separate service project.

Comment: but that is only an issue with the ASP.MVC setup (that should be easily solved if you inject the dependencies) - what I was talking about the example code for the identity providers and stuff you want to use with F# - overall it would really help if you had some concrete question - those broad ones can only be discussed but never answered

Comment: Thanks @Carsten in that case I'll narrow my question: I've found this tutorial [link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2011/04/04/f-code-first-development-with-entity-framework-4-1.aspx) So question: Is this still valid in terms of F#4 and EF7

Comment: of course it is - some things are just a bit harder in F# because you have no tooling support (for example the Designer stuff you would most likely use for EF and C#) - but all those will finally output code you can translate in F# - on the other Hand if I would use EF I would do the DB-part in C# and the rest in F# - if you want all F# look at the type-providers IMO

Comment: I'm exploring similar setup but with all code in F#. Right now I have test code in C# with Identity and authentication using Google Auth. I took the relevant parts from [aspnet Github sample](https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/tree/dev/samples/IdentitySample.Mvc), personally I don't use views, as this is JS single-page REST app.